# Laravel - Update dynamic fields of multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have multiple tables. I want to update data on tables from a single form. I am able to update the `Student` table but data on `Interest` are not updated.
My Edit form has dynamic fields for texts and images where user can add as many fields.

**Edit form** looks like
[image: Upon editing previously added fields & images should display.]

**Student**

```
public function interests() {
    return $this->hasMany(Interest::class, 'student_id');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Interest.php**

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}
```

**UpdateController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{        
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $std = Student::findOrFail($id);

    $imagepath = public_path('images');

    if ($request->hasFile('studentimage')) 
    {
        $file = $request->file('studentimage');
        $rules = array('file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg'); 
        $validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);

        if($validator->passes()) 
        {
            $fileNameExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileNameForm = str_replace(' ', '_', $fileNameExt);
            $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameForm, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $fileExt = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$fileExt;

            $pathToStore = public_path('images');

            $studentimage = '/images/'.$fileNameToStore;  
            Image::make($file)->resize(1366, 531)->save($pathToStore . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $fileNameToStore);


        }

        $requestData['studentimage'] = "images/{$fileNameToStore}";

    }

    $std->update($requestData);
    session()->flash('message', 'Successfully updated.');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Is it showing any SQL error while inserting?? if yes, can you post it here..

Comment: @VajiraPrabuddhaka No errors. Update method executed successfully. But Interests data are not updated.